# How to export all functions inside PHP extension?

Tags: php, c++, c, php-extension, dllexport

I opened php_sqlite.dll & php_sockets.dll using Depends.exe. I saw only 1 function in both: get_module

How can I export all functions in extension to dll files when compiling the .dll? AFAIK, ZEND_FUNCTION is used to declare functions in the modules. Please kindly advise. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you want to call functions in a PHP module?

Comment: yes, directly from C/C++ , instead of going into PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't simply expose all functions. If it isn't your extension, just do what zend does - call `get_module()`, get the function descriptions & function pointers.

If it is your extension however, consider whether you are mainly targeting PHP, C++ or want to support whatever comes your way.
If you are mainly targeting PHP and the C++ access is an exception, just do what zend does. In both other cases a C++ core with just some interfacing to PHP is what you should go for - interface generators like [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) can ease your job and generate the PHP interface for you.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. I target to use php extensions in C++, but not in PHP. I need to use some of those extensions in desktop GUI instead of server environment. And I do development with Nokia Qt C++. PHP has excellent extensions that one should use instead of rewriting.

Comment: Then maybe you should consider using the underlying (C) libraries of that php modules and not the modules themselves.

Comment: As a sidenote, what exactly do you need from the PHP modules that C++-specific libraries like Boost, POCO or Qt don't have?

Comment: I'm accustomed to PHP API and they have quite intuitive functions like file_get_contents, file_put_contents, csv processing, mysql & mysqli which get job done quickly :) Doing MySQL/database in general in POCO & Qt is not that as fast as in PHP (in terms of API simplicity).

Comment: Maybe, but if you weigh that against the time you'll need to wrap the PHP modules conveniently in C++ (e.g. C++s static typing vs. PHPs dynamic typing) i don't think you benefit from them.